# how transformer model encoder out put from fcn to decoder and then how things are done at decoder

Tags: deep-learning, theory, transformer-model

I have read many articles about transformer model, they all focus on encoder side but no one explain how the output from fully connected network in encoder is processed at the decoder side. I need your help to understand the following questions.

1. could you please explain how the output encoded tokens are processed at decoder side with some mathematical notation.
2. how cross attention in decoder compute inputs and does it take from encoder last fully connected layer or it also takes k, V vectors from each encoder layer?...please explain it in detail how cross attention works.
3. As mentioned in article the decoder take the previous output as a input to the decoder to predict next word. does it do the same during training ?